# MySql query for crosstable select

Tags: mysql

packages:
package_id, user_id

transactions:
product_id,user_id,package_id

I want to select rows in transactions that have package_id null or 0
but only when there are other transactions with same user_id where package id is greater than 0
is that possible. Sorry for bad English... I tried goggling it, but couldn't guess a correct question for Google query.

I know that title is not ok, so anybody please propose a better one.

Gwynnbleid1

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Where have you got struck ? Is it in understanding the query ? Also, you have to show us what you have done so far.

Comment: I would just like to let everyone know about a nice website for questions like this (it is an SQL prettifier with lots of options): http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this...I try to avoid sub-selects at all costs, so it can get crazy and a bit confusing, and I never truly know if it works until I try.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.*
FROM   packages P
       LEFT JOIN transactions T
         ON P.user_id = T.user_id
       LEFT JOIN transactions T2
         ON T.user_id = T2.user_id
WHERE  ( T.package_id IS NULL
          OR T.package_id = 0 )
       AND T2.package_id > 0
```

Comment: This gave me exacly what I wanted. First answer was also ok, but i will mark this as final asnwer since this approach is supposed to be more efficient. Thanks to all of you :) I always knew that this site is a best place to post question, but this was the first time I had a question myself.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you all the transactions for `package_id > 0` for users who have at least one other transaction with a `NULL` or `0` `package_id`.

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user_id IN 
(SELECT user_id FROM transactions WHERE package_id IS NULL OR package_id = 0) 
AND package_id > 0;
```

Comment: While this will work, especially as a one-off, using IN is not recommended with large record sets, it can really slow your query down. If you are going to be running this query in an application several times, there are more efficient ways.

Comment: @invertedSpear: I definitely prefer JOINs to IN for performance, but I figured this was easier to understand.

Comment: This one worked for me and could be marked as answer, but in regard to above comments I decided to mark other way approach. Sorry (I tried to mark all good answers cause I will only use this query to search for errors (all transations should be in package, or all of them should be set to null))

Comment: you're right, in's (especially in this case) are a lot simpler to understand, I've caught myself using them more often than I should.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.* FROM

(SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS WHERE (package_id = 0 or package_id is null)) A
(SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS WHERE package_id is not null) B

WHERE A.userID = B.userID
```

Comment: This one gave me an error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE package_id is not null) B WHERE A' at line 4
I don't know why...

Comment: FWIW, the error is a missing comma on line 2 after `package_id is null)) A`